# capture a user list, spring security, with boolean value

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, boolean, scaffolding

So I have been investigating this for a while and I am not sure that my approach is actually possible. I am very new to groovy, and really struggling.

I am writing a web-app which can be used to monitor time usage on IT projects. I am writing my project class which will hold information on each project, and I want to be able to affiliate individual users to projects making check boxes on the scaffolded gsp page for each user. As such I want to create a boolean value for each user against each project.

I have been stabbing around using the .each() command in my domain class in an attempt to achieve this. as below. Any help from anyone would be so appreciated I can't begin to say.

```
package timetracker2

import java.util.Date;
import grails.timesecurity.*

class Project {

  String name
  int pmgNumber
  Projectmanagers fullName
  String description
  Date estimatedCompletionDate
  String estimatedDuration
  Date dateCreated
  Map attachedUsers 

  def Person.each() {
      String username = Person.username
      attachedUsers = [username:Boolean.valueOf()]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem/question you have?

Comment: ummmm how to make the above actually work. I think my approach is completely wrong. question is how do I make a list of all users in the system, and then create a boolean value for each user in the list against eaach project?

Comment: OR is it possible to create a list of only selected users which appear as a boolean value in the scaffold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [many-to-many](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany) relationship.

```
class Project {
    static hasMany = [persons: Person]
...
}

class Person {
    static hasMany = [projects: Project]
...
}

// get persons affiliated with a project:
project.persons

// get a person's projects:
person.projects
```

In your view you can then show a list of all projects, with those selected that are also in person.projects.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you very much. I have seen these relation manipulations before but did not know how they would influence the scaffold view. Thanks again.

Comment: Grails scaffolding does not support many-to-many relations as of now. You will have to adjust the view yourself, either by overriding the view of the project, or by changing the template files for scaffolding.